# How to set a global before PHPUnit's skeleton-test is run

Tags: php, phpunit

We set a global in our prepend file used to form the path for our require_once calls.  For example:

```
require_once($GLOBALS['root'].'/library/particleboard/JsonUtil.php');
```

Problem is, when I run PHPUnit's skeleton test builder, the prepend file is not run, so the global is never set.  When I run

```
cd /company/trunk/queue/process; phpunit --skeleton-test QueueProcessView
```

PHPUnit tries to resolve a require_once in QueueProcessView, but since the $GLOBALS['root'] is never set, I get a fatal error when including the required file.

For example, to PHPUnit, what should be

```
require_once(/code/trunk/library/particleboard/JsonUtil.php)
```

is resolved as

```
require_once(/library/particleboard/JsonUtil.php)
```

Notice the missing root.

Does anyone know if the skeleton-test code has some way to call PHP file before it is run?  In this I could set my GLOBAL['root'] in this file.

Any other creative solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way as you can bootstrap a regular test suite, you can also do much the same for the skeleton generation

```
phpunit --bootstrap prepend.php --skeleton-test QueueProcessView
```

I tested this with three files:

test.php:

```
<?php   
require_once($GLOBALS['root'].'/confirmedToRun.php');
class test
{
   function doStuff()
   {
   }
}
```

prepend.php:

```
<?php   
$root = "/tmp/";
```

confirmedToRun.php:

```
<?php   
echo __FILE__;
```

Running `phpunit --bootstrap prepend.php --skeleton-test test` to generate the skeleton class, testTest.php - also runs the `confirmedToRun.php` file.

```
phpunit --bootstrap prepend.php --skeleton-test test
PHPUnit 3.4.2 by Sebastian Bergmann.

/tmp/confirmedToRun.php
Wrote skeleton for "testTest" to "/home/me/tmp/testTest.php".
```

Comment: Thanks Alister!  That's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  I simply edited the PHPUnit/Util/Test.php file to include my reference.  Not the most elegant solution, but since the rest of the framework allows you to call a bootstrap file, I can live with this one hacked utility.